# audio player return DOMException: The element has no supported sources

Tags: reactjs, blob, html5-audio

I am working with audio player
The response of get song, blob object, and url return by URL.createObjectURL like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1gkY.png)

The headers of blob link show [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVAGM.png)

And "DOMException: The element has no supported sources" appeared
.Please help me

I coded like this

```
            const blob = new Blob([response.data],{type: 'audio/mpeg'})
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            
            audio.current.src = url
```

Comment: What do you mean by "enter image description here"? Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question!